# Given a polynomial $p(x)$ in $\mathbb Z_6[x]$, it is possible to construct a ring $R$ such that $p(x)$ has a root in $R$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

> Prove or disprove: Given a polynomial $p(x)$ in $\mathbb Z_6[x]$, it
>   is possible to construct a ring $R$ such that $p(x)$ has a root in
>   $R$.

For this exercise I think about complex numbers. Since each polynomial has complex root we can take complex numbers ring. Is it a right solution or I am missing something?

Comment: The integers modulo $6$ don't embed in the complex numbers, so there's no way to put make sense of applying a complex number to $p(x)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just follow the usual construction and embed $\mathbb{Z}_6 \hookrightarrow \mathbb{Z}_6 [X]/(p(x))$ (provided that $p$ is not constant).

Comment: The idea: add a new "thing" that is solution of $p(x)$ by definition.